# How do I get the filename and line number in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would like to get the current filename and line number within a Perl script. How do I do this?

For example, in a file call `test.pl`:

```
my $foo = 'bar';
print 'Hello, World!';
print functionForFilename() . ':' . functionForLineNo();
```

It would output:

```
Hello, World!
test.pl:3
```

Comment: For the current ***input file*** (not the Perl ***source file*** as here), see *[How to get the filename of the current file in a Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663982)*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are available with the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` tokens, as documented in [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) under "Special Literals":

> The special literals __FILE__, __LINE__, and __PACKAGE__ represent the current filename, line number, and package name at that point in your program. They may be used only as separate tokens; they will not be interpolated into strings. If there is no current package (due to an empty package; directive), __PACKAGE__ is the undefined value.

Comment: Provided they haven't been diddled.

Comment: @tchrist: yes, source filtering screws up a lot of things :)

Comment: Not just those. You can also modify the values `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` give you using `#line` directives, and then there's a couple of perl bugs that cause `__LINE__` to be slightly off in various cases.

Comment: `perl -x` will also reset `__LINE__`, but I was thinking about `#line` directives, not about the madness otherwise known as source filters.

Answer (score 11):

The `caller` function will do what you are looking for:

```
sub print_info {
   my ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
   ...
}

print_info(); # prints info about this line
```

This will get the information from where the sub is called, which is probably what you are looking for.  The `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` directives only apply to where they are written, so you can not encapsulate their effect in a subroutine.  (unless you wanted a sub that only prints info about where it is defined)

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
print __FILE__. " " . __LINE__;
```