# How to get the filename of the current file in a Perl one-liner

Tags: perl

Is it possible to get the current filename (from a list of files) in a Perl one-liner like this below?

```
perl -lane 'if ($_=~/my_value/) { print $_; }' *.txt
```

Comment: For the Perl ***source*** file name itself, see e.g. *[How do I get the filename and line number in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071447)*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The name of the variable is `$ARGV`. You can find out about it in [perlvar: `$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV).

Comment: That's a confusing name for that variable.

Comment: The variable name is a hold-over from C, where people often use `argv` as the list of command line arguments: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: @brian d foy: Implicit the first one (index 0)?